# How do I dynamically add items to a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I am using custom adapter to display a ListView.

It is working fine.

But i need to add three items to the ListView. How do I add them and have them display?

I tried `notifydatasetchanged()` method that is not working.

Comment: put your code of custom adapter..

Comment: +1 "Thanks in advance" removed ;)  There is no thanks in advance.  The checkmark and up vote are thanks for correct answers.

Comment: @BillMote : keep it up..

Answer (score 3):

You have to add items to your list using `list.add(...)` then you tell the adapter with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 2):

For adding item into the listview you must use the List/ArrayList object. Using this you can perform add/edit/delete operation on listview item data and this list set into your adapter to get the data from list/arraylist and set into list item.

Ok now suppose I have listview and want to add new item just add item into the list/arraylist object and notify to the adapter like this

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

oncreate(){
   // initi listview, adapter and set the myList object into adapter object and then set the adapter into listview


}

// on button click from somewhere
public void onClick(View view){
    myList.add("hello friends");// you can add your data here into list object
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```